# MyBatis and SQL, best performance query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, mybatis

I would know that is the best way to do a query linke the following. I need to optimize performances and to avoid useless operation in the DB (postgresql).

User will input a series of filters, which are a couple of values ("id_meta" and "value"), which will reduce the numbers of rows I exctract from "meta" table. Those fields are not PK.

Here is an **example**, the table has more column, but those are the interested ones.

```
| id_meta | value      | id_ud |
| ------- |:----------:| -----:|
| 1       | pippo      | 45    |
| 2       | 10         | 45    |
| 3       | 21/05/2010 | 45    |
| 1       | pluto      | 35    |
| 2       | 14         | 35    |
| 3       | 22/05/2010 | 35    |
```

and so on... if users inputs the couple (1:pippo) and (2:14) the query will return 0 rows, because there is not a (2:14) for the id_ud returned by the first filter (45).

it can't give different values for the same id_meta at the same time, things like (1:pippo) AND (1:pluto) are not possible

So basically every couple of filters is a nested subqueries, which reduce the numbers of the first result set. If user will give 3 filters, I would do 3 subqueries

```
select id_ud 
from meta 
where id_meta = 12 
      and value = '45'
      and id_ud in (select id_ud 
                    from meta 
                    where id_meta = 10 
                    and value = 1000 
                    and id_ud in (select id_ud 
                                  from meta 
                                  where id_meta = 6 
                                  and value = 'll'
                                 )
                   )
```

I need to count the number of the returned rows AND I have another condition

```
select count(id_ud) 
from meta 
where id_ud in (select ID_UD 
                from documento 
                where stato = 'ACHIVIATO' 
                and id_cat_doc = 2)
and value= '2010' 
and id_meta = 12 and id_ud in (select id_ud 
                               from meta 
                               where id_meta = 10 
                               and value = 1000 
                               and id_ud in (select id_ud 
                                             from meta 
                                             where id_meta = 6 
                                             and value = 'll'
                                             )
                              );
```

So basically I have to dinamically create a nested subqueries with MyBatis and count the returned values, as the last example above. Is there a way to avoid all that subqueries, pheraps using ANY, ALL, UNION or other SQL constructs ?

Thanks, please feel free to add more detail, I'm not sure i explained clearly my problem...

### UPDATE

I'm trying to build this query with mybatis

```
    select 
        count (id_ud)
    from 
        documento
    where
        stato = 'ARCHIVIATO'
        and id_categoria_documentale = #{param2, jdbcType=BIGINT}
        <foreach item="value" index="key" collection="param1.entrySet()" open=" and id_ud in ("
            separator=" and id_ud in (" close="))">
            select
                id_ud
            from
                meta
            where
                id_meta = #{key, jdbcType=INTEGER}
                and value = #{value, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
        </foreach>
```

Where param1 is the map object containing all the user filters. I have problems adding the correct numbers of closing )... Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select count(id_ud) 
from meta mt1
join (select ID_UD from documento where stato = 'ACHIVIATO' and id_cat_doc = 2) doc on (doc.ID_UD = mt1.id_ud)
join (select id_ud from meta where id_meta = 10 and value = 1000 ) mt2 on (mt2.id_ud = mt1.id_ud)
join (select id_ud from meta where id_meta = 6 and value = 'll' )  mt3 on (mt3.id_ud = mt2.id_ud)
where value= '2010' and id_meta = 12
```

this should be faster..

EDIT:
another way:

```
select count(id_ud) 
from meta mt1
join (select ID_UD from documento where stato = 'ACHIVIATO' and id_cat_doc = 2) doc on (doc.ID_UD = mt1.id_ud)
where (1=1) --always true 
or (value= '2010' and id_meta = 12) and (id_meta = 6 and value = 'll') and (id_meta = 10 and value = 1000) --user conditions
```

and you can build dynamic query in your script/program

Comment: I've tried, but it seems slower to me. With an example database of 500 rows  and with 2 subqueries for users filters, it needs 6 more ms rather than the subqueries one. Does the result will change if I would have 6000 + rows ?
By tha way, How can I do that with MyBatis and Mybatis Generator ?

Comment: i think you can do this in other way  - you can see this in edit

Answer (score 0):

Your query is more or less identical to tag search, fulltext search, or dating search. Therefore it makes sense to use a search method already optimized for such cases.

Fulltext, which fortunately postgres supports, seems a good match.

I suggest coalescing the whole "meta" table into a column in the table "documento" which would represent the tags. Let's name this column... "tags."

It would contain "1=pippo 2=14 3=21/05/2010" for id_ud=45

You will probably have to use something other than a ":", disable lexing and other fancy options etc, in order to convince the full text search engine to consider your tokens as "words".

This should be quite fast.

Another option, since you have dates, is to give these dates real columns in the table "documento". For example if you have a publication date, why not put it in a column with an index on it? This will also allow range (date BETWEEN ... AND ...) searches. Relational databases like to have their data in columns... it's the standard, and also the most efficient... "meta" tables like you have are always cumbersome.

Multiple independent column indexes can be combined using a bitmap index scan, which is quite fast.

Another approach is to put the tags inside the "documento" table, but inside a hstore. This way all the tags for one record are on the same line, and you can use partial index on the keys in the hstore.